# Any open source or free Web Twain Scanner

Tags: javascript, web, scanning

I already searching for some web twain sdk, but i cant afford the price. Is there really any open source or free web twain sdk that can access scanner from web api or javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Dynamic-Web-TWAIN](https://github.com/Dynamsoft/Dynamic-Web-TWAIN)

> "a cross-platform scanning SDK designed for web document management
> applications. With just a few lines of JavaScript code, you can
> develop robust web applications to scan documents, edit images and
> save them to file systems".

This is the only one I have come across. You can also search for more on github.

Comment: I am also searching for a good / affordably price solution. The above option is very expensive for me: +- 3000$ per server.

Answer (score 1):

[I've found someone suggesting this...:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45544995)
Yes, there is an application that enables scanning on the remote machine. When someone opens the browser a connection between the web browser and that local machine application is established...

Please try this: [ScanAppForWeb](https://github.com/mgriit/ScanAppForWeb)

Comment: At the moment, this looks spammy.  You should really declare if you have an affiliation to the site.